# Populating and manipulating jqGrid's search widget with selenium doesn't seem to trigger DOM form events

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, dom, jqgrid

I'm wrestling with this problem now for well over a week.   Our application uses jqGrid.   I'm trying to do a search (in Selenium WebDriver 2.35 - it has to be that version for various reasons).

The jqGrid looks like:

[JqGrid Search widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY3Eh.png)

When my Java-based Selenium WebDriver scripts change the search column to 'Name' (not an unreasonable task...) the search text field loses focus - it is circled in red in the attached image.   However, doing a simple element.sendkeys("search") text does manage to populate the text field.

The problem is that when the automation clicks the 'Find' button, the data in the text field is not sent to the REST API backing it (eg. filter : {"column":"name", "operator":"cn", "data":""} )

When the response is received, the grid displays the same information.   I believe the problem is that the element.sendKeys() method does not seem to generate a  'change' event.

I've tried the following to generate a DOM change event:

1. doing a click on some element within the Search widget.
2. tabbing to the the next field -  element.sendKeys(Keys.Tab)
3. attempt to set the focus in the text box using Javascript/JQuery

`JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   String script = "var searchtxt=document.evaluate('"+xpathQuery+"',       document,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue; "+
            "$(searchtxt).focus()";
    jse.executeScript(script);`
   - to no avail

4. attempt to trigger a 'change' event also through Javascript/Jquery to no avail
   e.g. $(searchtxt).trigger('change')

I'm running out of ideas.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You wrote that you have to use version 2.35 of Selenium WebDriver. It seems that you understand that different versions of the same product works in a little different way. jqGrid too.

Comment: Looks like we are using 5.0.2 Guriddo of jqGrid.

Comment: You can just open `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and to see the version in the comment. You can verify whether the same problem exist in free jqGrid by changing the URLs of jqGrid files to the URLs described in [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If you would have no problem in free jqGrid, that you have the bug in Guriddo. I develop free jqGrid fork and can't help you with Guriddo jqGrid JS.

Comment: Yes, I went in to the .js file and we just started using 5.1.0 Guirrdo (not 5.0.2 as previously mentioned).  I'm not sure if we are able to use free jqGrid, I'm not the developer but I can ask them to try it.  Thank you for the hint

Comment: Do you verified whether the same problem exist in Guirrdo 5.1.0 and in free jqGrid 4.13.0? The question is: whether you have the problem in your code or in jqGrid. Temporary changing the URLs to free jqGrid and running the test is easy. The question which fork to use is **another question**.

Comment: Hehe...I'm not that fast Oleg,  I'll have to download the libraries and change some things around to do so.   I will try this though.

Comment: If your company have bought the license of Guirrdo then you have support and can post the question [here](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js). Many people used old version of jqGrid before and just made update to the new version without to know that the product can't be used for free (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and the license is changed too (no more MIT). I recommend you to clear the question about the licenses.

Comment: So I tried the same test with the latest Chrome browser and selenium chrome driver and the automated test doesn't have a problem populating the text field and setting the focus appropriately.  

As mentioned earlier, we're constrained to Firefox 24 and Selenium 2.35 because of the apps use of GWT.   I need to find out what the last compatible version of jqGrid is with Firefox 24.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand **which version and fork of jqGrid** you used in your last test: free jqGrid 4.13.1 or Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.1.0?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Oleg.   I tested both free jqGrid 4.13.1 and Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.1.0.   In either jqGrid version, the automated test populated the Search widget's text field but did not put the focus in the search field and consequently didn't generate the necessary DOM form event ('change' I think) where the content in the text field was sent to the backend API.   

I tried the same automated test with Gurrido but with the latest Chrome browser instead and didn't have a problem.  I think the problem lies in Selenium and Firefox 24.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you do with respect of Selenium, how you opens Searching Dialog of jqGrid, how you fill the data, simulates the buttons and so on. In general you can applying "change" event **before** applying the filter should solve your problem. For example `$(".input-elm").change();`. One tip only: try to make small (50ms) timeout between `change` and click on the "Search" button.

Comment: I am using Selenium Java WebDriver.   I was populating the field using WebElement elem.sendKeys("searchtext");  And sure enough your suggestion of $('.input-elm').change();  did the trick!    Thank you very much.   Can you make your suggestion an answer so i can accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not use Selenium myself, but I'd like give you a tip. Searching Dialog hold internally the filter as string and update it every time inside of `change` handle. If the user fill the data interactively and then clicks on "Search" button then the `change` event should be send automatically. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid and I includes [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L297-L301) of code where I trigger `change` event once more on all input elements (on `$(".input-elm")` elements).

Thus I hope the problem should not exist in free jqGrid. If you have to use Guriddo jqGrid JS then I would recommend you to include explicit call of

```
$(".input-elm").change();
```

before Selenium will simulate click on "Search" button.

Comment: Thanks so very much, Oleg.  I had been wrestling with this problem for over a week!

Comment: @markb: You are welcome! I'd like that I could help you.